# iReport Designer : Extra space at the end of detail band (Jasper Reports)

Tags: java, jasper-reports, report, reporting, ireport

I am creating an invoice using Jasper Reports for my Java based web application. I have a header, detail and a footer/summary section.
Now in the detail section I need a table (rectangle) with dark lines in the background.
When I add a line at the bottom, a gap comes between the last printed line of the detail section and the line. Is there a way to fix it ?

I tried the following:

1. isfloatcolumnfooter.
2. frame in background
3. 1 px band size

..Nothing worked

[image]

I can provide more details etc. if needed. Please help

```
<detail>
<band height="23" splitType="Stretch">
<line>
<reportElement x="43" y="0" width="1" height="23" uuid="bfd7f8a1-0415-4ede-9d92-a1aa913b55e2"/>
</line>
<textField>
<reportElement x="56" y="5" width="100" height="13" uuid="ca532d23-ffd3-4d77-81af-4520fdb6b667"/>
<box>
<pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
<topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
<leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
<bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
<rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
</box>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{invoiceline_description}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField>
<reportElement x="294" y="5" width="60" height="13" uuid="29d2fc03-81b9-4986-a761-f42aa6509a03"/>
<textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{invoiceline_invoicedquantity}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField>
<reportElement x="383" y="5" width="71" height="13" uuid="e5672484-d1ff-4dc5-afa6-76d301433f1a"/>
<textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{invoiceline_unitprice}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField>
<reportElement x="475" y="5" width="73" height="13" uuid="dc6f3594-64b0-4684-8db4-68c96dea8697"/>
<textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{invoiceline_linenetamount}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<line>
<reportElement x="270" y="0" width="1" height="23" uuid="8bd2e847-d108-43b5-859c-5141c4a720a3"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement x="379" y="0" width="1" height="23" uuid="4fea96bf-8f1c-4ece-b7aa-eefec2d07c5d"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement x="467" y="0" width="1" height="23" uuid="9b742277-ff58-4ca5-ac75-3e5c372093e9"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement x="555" y="0" width="1" height="23" uuid="2290f18b-b212-47e0-802d-639eb0cb291a"/>
</line>
<line>
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1" height="23" uuid="5c0f3589-1021-4d24-bed6-5ce84ef49b2a"/>
</line>
<textField>
<reportElement x="9" y="5" width="26" height="13" uuid="0da653fa-261e-4b2f-89a0-6cd29fac9e32"/>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{COLUMN_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
</band>
</detail>
<columnFooter>
<band height="12">
<frame>
<reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="11" uuid="1eb2763d-ed9b-4bcb-b5dd-6a18fcea3e87"/>
<box>
<pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
<topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
<leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
<bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
<rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
</box>
</frame>
</band>
</columnFooter>
```

Comment: A screenshot would make your question clearer.

Comment: Ok.. I have added the figure.

Comment: Is your report  going to exceed more than one page ?

Comment: No.. It will be one page long only